# Is the function integrable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Is the function $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{10^n},  & \text{if $x$ }\in(2^{-(n+1)},2^{-n}) \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}, f:[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}$$ 
integrable? Find $\int_0^{1}f$.

My attempt: It is easily noticed that the function is continuous on intervals between 0 and 1 (In my language it is called "fragmentary continuous" but I don't know how it is said in English.) Moreover, the function is bounded and therefore is integrable.

Then, $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{2^{-(0+1)}}^{2^{-0}}f(x)dx+\int_{2^{-2}}^{2^{-1}}f(x)dx+...+\int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}}f(x)dx+...=\int_{{1\over 2}}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{{1\over 4}}^{{1\over 2}}f(x)dx+...+\int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^{2^{-n}}f(x)dx+...={1\over 10^{0}}{(1-{1\over 2})}+{1\over 10^{1}}{({1\over 2}-{1\over 4})}+...+{1\over 10^{n}}({1\over 2^n}-{1\over 2^{(n+1)}})+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{1\over 10^{n}}({1\over 2^n}-{1\over 2^{(n+1)}})}$. How can I simplify that? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Distribute, you get the difference of two geometric series

Comment: Interesting. However, I find it hard to do so for this is a sum and I am not sure how it is acceptable.

Comment: It is, if a series converges, then it's negative converges and if two series converges then their sum converges (I'm sure you know it)

Comment: It is a plain geometric series.

Comment: I prefer RRL's answer.

Comment: Does anyone know how it is called; a function that is continuous on some separated intervals\fragmentary continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^1f(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \int_{2^{-(k+1)}}^{2^{-k}}10^{-k}dx= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n 10^{-k}\frac{2^{k+1}-2^k}{2^k2^{k+1}}$$

Comment: I got that identity in the last row. Or, is this form of the identity necessary for me to get ahead?

Comment: Yes -- that summand simplifies greatly

Comment: My problem is that I think that the limit is tenuous but when $n$ is as little as possible, the sums are big and significant. They won't be achieved that way. Is it not so?

Comment: That simplifies to $ \sum_{k=0}^n 10^{-n}\frac{2^{n+1}-2^n}{2^n2^{n+1}}= \sum_{k=0}^n 10^{-n}\frac{2^{n}(2-1)}{2^n2^{n+1}} = \frac1{2} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{20^{n}}$  - which clearly converges

Comment: Sorry for typo -- should be $\frac1{2} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{20^{k}}$

Comment: Thank you. Now all there is to do for me is to find out what such a limit can be.

Comment: But, is the integral defined on $2^{-n}$ for example? The interval is open...

Comment: @Meitar: The function is integrable since it is bounded and discontinuous only on a countable (zero measure) set.  We can compute the integral as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^1 f(x) \, dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{2^{-(n+1)}}^1 f(x) \, dx$ -- which reduces to the sum of the infinite geometric series.  The sum of a geometric series is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} r^n = 1/(1-r)$ for $|r| < 1$.  In this case $r = 1/20$.

Comment: I have just arrived at it! Good to have your approval. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome.